# sequelize does not set standard primary key "id" in v6.6.5

Tags: sequelize.js

I updated the sequelize package in our project in two steps from 4.41.0 over 5.22.2 to 6.6.5.
With 5.22.2 everythings OK (besides, "pg" and "sequelize-fixtures" had to be updated to 7.6.0 respectively 1.2.0). But with v6.6.5 ...

```
ProductCompatibility.create({
  product_id: someNumber,
  compatible_product_id: someOtherNumber,
});
```

... Sequelize creates the record but does not set the default primary key "id". The Model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const ProductCompatibility = sequelize.define('ProductCompatibility', {    
    product_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    compatible_product_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    created_at: { type: Sequelize.DATE },
    updated_at: { type: Sequelize.DATE },
  }, {
    tableName: 'product_compatibilities',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  });


  return ProductCompatibility;
};
```

When I add this to the Model, ...

```
const ProductCompatibility = sequelize.define('ProductCompatibility', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },    
        ...
```

..., the id will be set.

That's OK for me, but I'd like to know, why the default behavior - setting the standard primary key id and auto increment it - does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize creates primary key fields automatically now. If you want to rename the id column name to product_id you'd need to define it in the model as the primary key or if you want to use a different datatype id. But if you just want a int auto increment PK you can leave out the field entirely.

```
module.exports = Model = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
        // To just have a "id" column that is an int and auto increment you can leave out the id field
        custom_model_id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID, // I like to use UUIDs
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        field: DataTypes.STRING
    })

    return Model
}
```

Comment: I don't want to rename the primary key name. I'm only wondering why sequelize does not set it in my case.

Comment: Oh then I must have misunderstood you. Not sure why then